# How to work out correlation between three data points in R and then inspect with scatterplot?

Tags: r, correlation, scatter-plot

My data is a csv file as follows which has been read to a value called var_x_degs:

[image]

This goes on for 500+ more rows. I need to visually inspect how well the three replicates "VarXCRep.1", "VarXCRep.2" and "VarXCRep.3" agree/correlate with each other using scatterplots.

My thought process was to calculate correlation between Rep.1 and Rep.2 because I am unable to use `cor()` for more than two variables. But when I run `cor(var_x_degs$VarXCRep.1, var_x_degs$VarXCRep.2)` I get back one value. How can I work out correlation between each of the rows, so that each row has its own correlation value? I suppose once I have that value I can at least make a scatterplot. Is there a way to draw correlation between all triplicates?

Comment: I am new to R to bear with me on this: I tried ```new <- data.frame(x1=var_x_degs$VarX1Rep.1, x2=var_x_degs$VarX1Rep.1, x3=var_x_degs$VarX1Rep.1)
M <- cor(new)``` but the output was just 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Comment: Yes because they are the same variable hence perfectly correlated? Run `cor(mtcars)` and see if that is similar to what you need.

Comment: Apologies, I tried '''new <- select(var_x_degs, VarX1Rep.1, VarX1Rep.2, VarX1Rep.3)
M <- cor(new) ''' would this make sense? I do have a spread now

Comment: Yes, I think that is what you want?

Comment: So my version of RStudio does not load qtlcharts. I was able to make the corrplot. Is there a way to use corrplot in scatter?

Comment: I honestly do not know, I have never created a scatter plot of correlations but you can use `ggplot2` to plot them and maybe color by name of the variable?

Comment: Many thanks for your support. Appreciate it.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. That includes a workable sample of data (not a picture of it) and a clear sense of what you're trying to get (a specific type of chart, for example). It's also unclear what you're trying to get correlations of—you said you want correlation coefficients per row? You'd only have one rep1 and one rep2 per row, so you're not going to get correlations from that